# Azure app service instance history and versions of patch updates

Tags: azure, azureportal, hotpatching

I have multiple App Service instances (not VMs). In the portal, where do I find when and if my instance was patched (e.g. on patch Tuesday)? Is there a log or a report?

Answer (score -1):

D'Seas,

The Kudu console enables you to query your App Service instance regarding the OS version and runtime versions patch update status. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-patch-os-runtime#how-can-i-query-os-and-runtime-update-status-on-my-instances) section of the document has a table on more information and where to find it.

Comment: Hi @KrishnaG, I don't see anything on that page indicating how to query for patch update info.  It says: "Access to registry location HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages, where information on "KB" patches is stored, is locked down."